# Pulling data from different rows in docx

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have written the code below. It works perfectly for what I want it to do which is pull data from a docx table and put it into a xlsx table. Is there a way that I can put all 3 sections that repeat into a simpler looking code?

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("C:/Users/documents/flie.docx") #Change document with tables name
doc = word.ActiveDocument

wb = Workbook()
filepath = 'C:/Users/excel.xlsx' 
wb.save(filepath)
wb=load_workbook(filepath)
sheet=wb.active

**
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
e = []
f = []
**

for i in (list(range(3,9)) + list(range(11,42))):
    table = doc.Tables(i)
 ** a.append(table.Cell(Row = 2, Column = 2).Range.Text)
    b.append(table.Cell(Row = 3, Column = 2).Range.Text)
    c.append(table.Cell(Row = 4, Column = 2).Range.Text)
    d.append(table.Cell(Row = 4, Column = 2).Range.Text)
    e.append(table.Cell(Row = 6, Column = 2).Range.Text)
    f.append(table.Cell(Row = 7, Column = 2).Range.Text) **

**
combine_table = {(table.Cell(Row = 2, Column = 1).Range.Text) : a,
                 (table.Cell(Row = 3, Column = 1).Range.Text) : b,
                 (table.Cell(Row = 4, Column = 1).Range.Text) : c,
                 (table.Cell(Row = 5, Column = 1).Range.Text) : d,
                 (table.Cell(Row = 6, Column = 1).Range.Text) : e,
                 (table.Cell(Row = 7, Column = 1).Range.Text) : f,
                 }     **     

labels = [list(range(1,38))]

df = pd.DataFrame(combine_table , index=labels)         
df.to_excel("excel.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested data structure, such as a dict of lists, mapping from table row number to the list of items. Then you can use `for` loops to store and access data for each row.

```
# Dict mapping row numbers to list of
# items found on that row.
row_data = {}

# Initialize it with empty lists.
for row in range(2, 8):
    row_data[row] = []

for i in (list(range(3,9)) + list(range(11,42))):
    table = doc.Tables(i)
    for row in range(2, 8):
        row_data[row].append(table.Cell(Row = row, Column = 2).Range.Text)

# Finally, combine them back together:
combine_table = {}
for row in range(2, 8):
    combine_table[table.Cell(Row = row, Column = 1).Range.Text] = row_data[row]
```

But a possibly more efficient way to approach this problem is to just look at the keys in column 1 directly, assuming they're the same for all tables.

You can also use [dict's `setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to initialize the item to an empty list the first time it's accessed. (Using a defaultdict would work as well.)

This assumes that column 1 of all tables is the same. It's different from what you're currently doing, which is only looking at column 1 of the *last* table you fetch. But perhaps this approach is more consistent.

```
combine_table = {}
for i in (list(range(3,9)) + list(range(11,42))):
    table = doc.Tables(i)
    for row in range(2, 8):
        combine_table.setdefault(
            table.Cell(Row=row, Column=1).Range.Text,
            []
        ).append(
            table.Cell(Row=row, Column=2).Range.Text
        )
```

At the end of the loop, `combine_table` will already have all the data that you wanted.